# Firefox CSS issue.Flex items overflowing.How to make flex items shrink?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

My component is getting hidden only in firefox browser.I assume this is a CSS issue.I have pasted an image from firefox console.Please explain what is this "lock" symbol and why half of my component is not appearing .

The flex items are getting hidden because they are overflowing.I tried using flex-wrap but this caused the text to appear in 2 rows.Can i make flex items shrink?

```
element {
}
.abcs.results .side {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #f3f4f5;
    border-left: 2px solid #cdcfd1;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 310px;
}
.abcs.results .side {
    display: none;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: abcs_default;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #5a5b5c;
    font-size: 14px;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

Comment: You should provide at least *some* code so that we can minimize the guesswork. Perhaps you can reproduce the problem with generic code.

Comment: i have included the css in question

Comment: Just a shot in the dark because I can't see the html, but does adding "box-sizing: border-box;" to ".side" do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding `min-width:0` to my component.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i make flex items shrink?

Yes.

The shorthand property `flex` is a concise way of writing out the following properties:

- `flex-grow`
- **`flex-shrink`**
- `flex-basis`

**eg.**

```
flex: 1 1 100px;
```

gives a (nominally `100px` wide) **flex-child-element** a *flex shrink factor* of `1`.

This means, when there isn’t enough space in the row, the flex-child-element will shrink at a factor of `1` relative to the rest of the flex items in the **flex-parent-element**.

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex